# Numpy: indicators to partition

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I am trying to represent a partition of the numbers 0 to n-1 in Python

I have a numpy array where the ith entry indicates the partition ID of number i. For instance, the numpy array

`indicator = array([1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0])`

indicates that numbers 3, 6, and 7 belong to the partition with ID 0. Numbers 0 and 1 belong to partition 1. 4 belongs to partition 2. And 2 and 5 belong to partition 3. Let's call this the *indicator* representation.

Another way to represent the partition would be a list of lists where the ith list is the partition with ID i. For the array above, this maps to

`explicit = [[3, 6, 7], [0, 1], [4], [2, 5]]`

Let's call this the *explicit* representation.

My question is **what is the most efficient way to convert the indicator representation to the explicit representation?** The naive way is to iterate through the indicator array and assign the elements to their respective slot in the explicit array, but iterating through numpy arrays is inefficient. **Is there a more natural numpy construct to do this?**

Comment: No, I do not think the explicit representation in the first place is so natural in numpy as the array becomes inhomogeneous. One can go around this e.g. by having an array of objects, but a list might be a more natural choice for your explicit representation. This does not change however that it is not a "natural" numpy construct.

Comment: what about a sparse matrix using one hot encoding ?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar yes, both solutions are along the lines of what I was looking for. I have selected a best answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using sorted indices and then splitting those into groups -

```
def indicator_to_part(indicator):
    sidx = indicator.argsort() # indicator.argsort(kind='mergesort') keeps order
    sorted_arr = indicator[sidx]
    split_idx = np.nonzero(sorted_arr[1:] != sorted_arr[:-1])[0]
    return np.split(sidx, split_idx+1)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [326]: indicator = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000))

In [327]: %timeit from_ind_to_expl(indicator) #@yogabonito's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 5.59 ms per loop

In [328]: %timeit indicator_to_part(indicator)
1000 loops, best of 3: 801 µs per loop

In [330]: indicator = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000))

In [331]: %timeit from_ind_to_expl(indicator) #@yogabonito's soln
1 loops, best of 3: 494 ms per loop

In [332]: %timeit indicator_to_part(indicator)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

Note that the output would be a list of arrays. If you have to get a list of lists as output, a simple way would be to use `map(list,indicator_to_part(indicator))`. Again, a performant alternative would involve few more steps, like so -

```
def indicator_to_part_list(indicator):
    sidx = indicator.argsort() # indicator.argsort(kind='mergesort') keeps order
    sorted_arr = indicator[sidx]
    split_idx = np.nonzero(sorted_arr[1:] != sorted_arr[:-1])[0]

    sidx_list = sidx.tolist()
    start = np.append(0,split_idx+1)
    stop = np.append(split_idx+1,indicator.size+1)
    return [sidx_list[start[i]:stop[i]] for i in range(start.size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for translating `indicator` to `explicit` using numpy only (no `for` loops, list comprehensions, itertools, etc.)
I haven't seen your iteration-based approach so I can't compare them but maybe you can tell me if it's fast enough for your needs :)

```
import numpy as np
indicator = np.array([1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0])
explicit = [[3, 6, 7], [0, 1], [4], [2, 5]]

def from_ind_to_expl(indicator):
    groups, group_sizes = np.unique(indicator, return_counts=True)
    group_sizes = np.cumsum(group_sizes)
    ordered = np.where(indicator==groups[:, np.newaxis])
    return np.hsplit(ordered[1], group_sizes[:-1])
```

`from_ind_to_expl(indicator)` gives

```
[array([3, 6, 7]), array([0, 1]), array([4]), array([2, 5])]
```

---

I have also compared the times of @Divakar's and my solution. On my machine @Divakar's solution is 2-3 times faster than mine. So @Divakar definitely gets an upvote from me :)

In the last comparison in @Divakar's post there's no averaging for my solution because there's only one loop - this is slightly unfair :P ;)